# Special characters with History.pushState using history.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate, history.js

I'm using the history.js JQuery plugin to update the title and create a history item. However when I do the following I get the text rather than the symbol:

```
History.pushState(data, '&#9658; ' + video.title.$t + ' - <?php echo $site_title; ?>', video.slug);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#9658;` is HTML syntax. Of course, HTML is not supported in the browser title. You should write `\u25BA` in JS.